# Haskell : repeat a given finite list indefinitely

Tags: list, haskell

I am a new one in Haskell and i am trying to define a function that it takes a finite list and create an infinite list adding in each repetition 1 to each element of the list. for example if i have the list [3,4,5] the function will generate the list [3,4,5,4,5,6,5,6,7....]

I'm thinking something like the loop, which will be infinite and it will add each loop one to each element and then add it in the list. But the problem is that I dont know exactly how to write it in Haskell!

Comment: Any attempt yourself?

Comment: there are not really loops in Haskell, it is all with recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Quick example in GHCi:

```
> let f x = x ++ (f $ map (+1) x)
> take 10 $ f [3,4,5]
[3,4,5,4,5,6,5,6,7,6]
```

Here, we define a recursive function `f`, that simply appends to the initial list the output of the recursive call with each number incremented by one. We can break it out to examine the function more closely.

GHCi will give you information on what type `f` is using

```
> :t f
f :: Num b => [b] -> [b]
```

This means it will work on any list of things with a `Num` instance (like `Int`).

So what does `f` do?

```
> let f x = x ++ (f $ map (+1) x)
            ^ -- Start with the initial list we pass in 
                      ^ -- Modify each element of that list and increment their values by 1. 
                      ^ -- This is where the `Num` constraint comes in
                  ^ -- Recursively call f with the new "initial list"
               ^ -- Append the result of calling f recursively to the initial list
```

Comment: And without recursion `concat (iterate (map (+1)) [1,2,3])`

Answer (score 2):

The components you need for this are:

- `map (+ 1) :: Num n => [n] -> [n]` to add 1 to each element of the list
- `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]` to create an infinite list where each element is a function over the previous element
- `concat :: [[a]] -> [a]` to flatten a list of lists
- `take 9 :: [a] -> [a]` which we will use to get the first 9 elements, for the sake of testing, to avoid trying to print an infinite list

```
λ> [3,4,5] & iterate (map (+ 1)) & concat & take 9
[3,4,5,4,5,6,5,6,7]
```